# C#: Anchored Panel won't resize properly

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I've a strange problem regarding auto sizing of a panel in a user control. This panel is anchored to all 4 sides of the user control.
But the anchoring not always works as it should:

If the user control is resized by resizing the form, the right and bottom anchors don't work. But if the control is resized by using a splitter which is in the form, it works correctly.
All other controls which are also affected by resizing work correctly, just this panel won't do.

I can't see the difference between resizing through a splitter and through a form.

Setting the size manually in the OnResize of the UserControl only works if the resizing is done by moving the splitter. If the resizing occurs by resizing the form, the heigth and the width of the panel won't change to the new values.

Edit: To make it more clear: The user control is added to a TabPage and set to Dock=DockType.Fill.

Edit2: To make it more complicated: This is the hierarchy the control is used:
The Form contains a splitter with 2 controls (A and B). (B) contains a user control (C) with a splitContainer. The split container->panel1 in (C) contains a tabcontrol (D). This tabcontrol (D) contains a user control (E) (in a tabpage) . This user control (E) has a splitcontainer (F) in which another usercontrol with a tabControl (G) is placed. This tabcontrol (G) has tabpages, and in this pages is the described user control (H) placed.

If I place the control (H) directly to the panel in the splitcontainer (C) everything works fine. Since all controls which are added to a splitcontainer or a tabpage are set to docktype=fill, I cannot see why the last control has this problems.

Is there any limitation in the Windows Forms framework which limits the amount of child controls?

Edit: I have uploaded a TestApplication with which you can reproduce this issue.
http://rapidshare.de/files/49092516/TestApplication.zip.html
It occurs only under Vista. Win XP and 7 work properly...
If you resize the form, the textBox with the "..." button won't resize, but if you resize via the vertical splitContainer, it works.

Comment: Could you paste the code code generated by the designer (where it links all the controls together)? My first guess is that your panel is anchored to a different control than you think (e.g. one of the panels of the split)

Comment: That would be way too much code to paste, but I checked the anchor more than once and it is set correctly (which is proven by a working resizing when using the splitter)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is a bug with deep nesting where the kernel runs out of stack space causing resizing, docking and anchoring to fail silently.

See https://web.archive.org/web/20140818095718/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953934

Comment: Awesome.  Was having this exact problem myself. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, I had no real hope of finding a solution to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: This is just about the only way to find http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953934.  It took hours of ninja-level googling to find this.  Thanks so much!!!  From my experience now, it appears apps are more prone to this issue when running through Citrix, especially Citrix on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: This saved me a ton of additional frustration!

Comment: I've been banging my head against the wall for the last two days.  Thank you!  This was my issue as well.

Comment: does this bug still exist 8yrs later?

Comment: Yes. Even in .Net Core 5.0! It's all fine on my development machine, but when I install app on the laptop it'all but crashed. Ech.

Answer (score 2):

You have talked about both "anchor" and "dock", which can serve similar purposes but act differently.  Your problem may be that you are trying to do both, and this is interfering with the behavior you want.  If not, perhaps try switching from the one to the other.

It sounds like you've double checked the ansectery of the control, but did you examine it with: View->Other Windows->Document Outline (a very handy tool I only recently discovered)?

Finally, while it doesn't directly solve your problem, it sounds like you have a very complicated UI, and your users may benefit if you were to spend some time to consider if you could simplify the UI.  Of course, I don't know your users or the purpose of the app, and what you have may be the best, but it sounds like it might be time to ask this question.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the document outline window, it's very handy. But because of the problem not only occurs in out application but also in the simple test application I can't figure out why it should be a problem with mixed up anchoring and docking. But I will check this out.
Concerning the UI: In the test application it look weird, but there is dynamic part in the real application and some items may be hidden. It is approved very handy by our customers ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the depth of nesting; controls can be nested arbitrarily deep. Anchoring and Docking generally do not play nicely with each other. I usually favor docking over anchoring, but, whichever solution you choose, you should probably avoid mixing them.

Comment: I tried several possibilities with anchoring and docking, but unfortunately this didn't help. It seems that must be a bug in the framework...